# How to resume the upgrade of package downloads (10.04 -> 10.10)

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, updates, stable-release-updates

I was trying to upgrade my 10.04 machine to 10.10 via the Update Manager.
It was downloading the packages (was not installing it).

Since I had to leave my place, I cancelled it in order to be able to resume it today.

But somehow, I don't find the upgrade option in the update manager anymore.

Any command line alternative to this?

I tried :

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But it said:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resume a *release upgrade*, you can run:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Apt's `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` only update packages in the current release.

Alternatively, you can run `sudo update-manager -c`, which will check for release upgrades:

[image]